# Has anyone recovered a Bitbucket Mercurial Repo that was deactivated in 2020?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

Bitbucket Mercurial support ended on July 1, 2020. My repos were deactivated at that time. Has anyone recovered their deactivated Mercurial repos, and how was that accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://bitbucket-archive.softwareheritage.org/) is the archive of all public Mercurial projects that were hosted on Bitbucket before they removed Mercurial support on July 1, 2020.

Some projects might be unavailable or incomplete because they were deleted or made private before we had a chance to archive them.